# node_modules different when deployed prod vs dev - angular 4

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I have a scenario where I have manipulated the actual npm package source.

When I "ng serve", it is working as expected, however when I "ng build --prod" the results are different.

As far as I know, there's only one copy of the package within node_modules folder?

Does anyone have an idea why it's different in results?

Comment: anyone know? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one copy of the package within node_modules. It is described here: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-dupe . You can use `npm dedupe` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe) to fix it.

Comment: But why would it pick a different copy when deploying prod vs ng serve?

Comment: I think that there might be different tools involved in the build process and while it is assumed that duplicated modules are equal, they might be picked randomly. You should publish your modified module as a different version and define it explicitly in your package.json as a dependency. You can do it locally using npm link or npm install with path to modified module.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look